# Redux / Redux Saga - how to wait for the store to update?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am using React with Redux and Sagas to create a card game simulator. I need to create a function which updates the redux state, waits for the new state and runs again. I'm not sure if / how something like that is possible in React Redux land. Below is a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
function endTurn() {
  // do something
}

function playerTurn(playerHand) {
  const decision = getPlayerDecision(playerHand);
  updatePlayerHand(decision); // this dispatches an action to update redux state

  // If player chose to 'Stand', the game ends.
  // Otherwise, it's player's turn again.
  if(decision === 'Stand') {
    endTurn();
  } else {
    // here I need the updated hand, how do I get it?
    playerTurn(updatedHand);
  }
}
```

An obvious solution would be to place this logic in 'componentWillReceiveProps' but it doesn't seem right and I'm sure it would end up being very buggy. Intuitively, it feels like a job for Redux Saga but I haven't been able to find anything relevant in the docs. Any suggestions?

SOLUTION: Krasimir's answer with the use of `yield select` pointed me in the right direction. Below is a simplified version of the code I ended up with:

```
import { put, takeEvery, select } from 'redux-saga/effects';

function* playPlayerTurn() {

  const playerHand = yield select(getPlayerHand);
  const decision = getPlayerDecision(playerHand);

  // some action that executes the decision
  // the action results in a change to playerHand
  yield put({
    type: `PLAY_PLAYER_DECISION`,
    decision,
  });

  // If player chose to 'Stand', the turn ends.
  // Otherwise, it's player's turn again.
  if(decision === 'Stand') {
    console.log('PLAYER OVER');
  } else {
    console.log('PLAYER AGAIN');
    yield put({
      type: `PLAY_PLAYER_TURN`,
    });
  }
}

export function* playerTurnWatcher() {
  yield takeEvery(`PLAY_PLAYER_TURN`, playPlayerTurn);
}
```

Essentially, I'm able to call the saga recursively

Comment: Why don't you return it from updatePlayerHand?

Comment: it dispatches a redux action, actions don't return

Comment: actions can return what you want, look at redux-thunk if you want a structured way to do that. Or you can just write an action for this case in mapDispatchToProps function, which can dispatch something but also return a separate result

Comment: Your components do not "wait for updates". They get passed new props that trigger a re-render. So the flow is as follows: User Interaction -> dispatch Action -> reducer updates state -> Connect component passes new props from store to the component -> component re-renders.

Comment: @trixn That's the issue, I need the function to access the new state before running again, but I don't want the function to be triggered by any of react lifecycle methods

Comment: @DominicTobias I didn't realise I could return from mapDispatchToProps. In that case, would it be possible for an action in mapDispatchToProps to return the new state? Could you point me to the relevant docs?

Comment: What do you mean with "running again"?

Comment: It's a recursive function, I need to grab the new state before each iteration

Comment: Dispatching actions does not and should not return anything. Especially not the new state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162806/discussion-between-user2634633-and-trixn).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume that you dispatch an action `PLAYER_HAND` where the payload is the `decision`.

```
import { select, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';

const waitForPlayerTurn = function * () {
  takeLatest(PLAYER_HAND, function * (decision) {
    // at this point the store contains the right `decision`
    if(decision === 'Stand') {
      endTurn();
    } else {
      playerTurn(yield select(getUpdateHand)); // <-- getUpdateHand is a selector
    }
  });
}
```

And of course you have to run the `waitForPlayerTurn` saga.

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I was looking for but `yield select` pointed me in the right direction. I've updated the question to show how I ended up solving it.